# Swift chat messaging layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout

I am working on a layout in Xcode8.2.1 Swift 3.  The following is what I have so far at runtime.  So my question could be answered already but I couldn't find what I was looking for so far.  This is how my runtime looks like at this time:

[image: runtime image]

My constraints are defined as following:

[image: Xcode code]

I am trying to layout the left side of the tableview for the image views.   The image view is stacked on top of label which is hidden if the message is of photo type.

I want the image views with the photo to display above the timestamp.  I have tried to that in the constraints where the left side uses views with "1" in the view name but is not correctly vertically aligned.

When messages are images I hide the textview and it works but for photo messages the image view is not correctly vertically aligned above the timestamp.

Is it possible to do with constraints or should I be looking at using stack views?

--edited
This is how I want it too look like where the message photo is on top of timestamp like below with green check:
[image]

thanks
-Sonam

Comment: would be easier to understand if you post the design or wanted result here

Comment: What I want is that when the message is of photo I want the image view to be vertically aligned on top of the timestamp and the timestamp will vertically position below the image view.

Comment: better way to do this , just set the height and width to each control and then wrap inside a Stackview , then you dont need to worry about all control and its easy to handle things

Comment: i think stackview seems to be what I am looking for. thanks